# php assigning exception to variable

Tags: php, exception

I was wondering if I can assign $e->getMessage() to a vaiable like so:

```
$errmsg = $e->getMessage();
```

I'm trying to mail() it to myself whenever an exception is caught from a try catch block and don't wanna screw up the mail body...

Comment: Yes, you can do it.

Comment: ty sir, wanted extra confirmation before I deploy the code

Comment: So you can't just try it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure :

```
$msg = 'foo';
try{
    throw new Exception('bar');
}catch (Exception $e){
    $msg = $e->getMessage();
}

echo $msg; // bar
```